# Blue "Default" line in a listview - where is it coming from?

Tags: c#, listview

Can someone please explain to me, what does this line mean, where is it coming from and how do I take it away? Thanks. 
[image]

Here is how I construct my listView:

```
                item1 = new ListViewItem(efef.InstFile.File);
                item1.SubItems.Add(efef.InstFile.DestDir);
                listViewDerivative1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });
```

Comment: Could you provide some code, such as the constructor for your listview, or how you assign a data structure to it, or any relevant code at all? Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item you have added does not belong to a `Group`, and so is added to the default group.

By defining a list of groups for your `ListView`, you can control what group each item comes under.

You can modify these values in the Form Builder or in code.  Try setting your `ListViewItem`'s `Group` property.

Comment: Thanks, what if I don't want any groups?

Comment: ShowGroups = false;